# Images poor in Kobo

Tags: kobo, image

I am creating an eBook with images. They appear OK on an iphone, but small and blurry in my Kobo. Is this a Kobo issue?

Comment: What images? What are their sizes? Are they grayscale or color? What resolution are you displaying them at? Do you have sample images/epub so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: The ebook is created using Serif PagePlus X9. One image is 441X113 pixels, 300 dpi, color. How do I attach an image sample?

Comment: If you edit your post, there should be an image tool in the toolbar. I *think* they've added it for new users such that it posts a link to the image. (After you've got 10 rep, you should be able to post the images themselves.) If it's not there, just post the image to imgur or someplace like that and add the link to your question.

Comment: beaker: Getting rep is now not so easy as how to say it.
Especially here on ebookSE.